# How to copy information from Excel into QGIS Attribute-Table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have an Attribute-Table that I need to add a row from Excel into it.
I saved the Excel as CSV (UTF-8) and was able to copy and paste one slot at a time.

When I tried to copy and paste more than one slot nothing happens i.e.there was no error  message or anything like that.

I am sure that there is a much faster way apart from copying and pasting it one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the table into QGIS and as I suppose you want put this data to a shapefile, right? You can do a join based on the same ID's in the shapefile and in the csv table.